# AES with OpenSSL in C++

Tags: c++, openssl, aes

I want to create a simple AES encryption project using OpenSSL in C++. I have written a simple class that implements this algorithm.

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include "openssl/rand.h"

class AESEncryption {
public:
    AESEncryption(const std::string& key) : key(key) 
    {
        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
        cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname("aes-256-cbc");
        if (!cipher) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Error: AES-256-CBC cipher not found.");
        }
    }

        std::string encrypt(const std::string& plaintext);
    std::string decrypt(const std::string& ciphertext, unsigned char* ivv);


    void writeCipherTextToFile(std::string ciphertext);

    unsigned char* getIV()
    { return iv; }
    
    unsigned char* getStaticIV()
    { return ivStatic; }

    void generateRandomIV()
    {       
        if (RAND_bytes(iv, EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(cipher)) != 1)
        throw std::runtime_error("Error generating random IV"); 
        std::memcpy(ivStatic, iv, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);
    }

private:
    const std::string key;
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH]; // zero initialization
    static unsigned char ivStatic[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    const EVP_CIPHER* cipher;
};

std::string AESEncryption::encrypt(const std::string& plaintext) 
    {   
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
        EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, cipher, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(key.c_str()), iv);
        
        int len = 0, ciphertext_len = 0;
        int plaintext_len = plaintext.length();

        std::string ciphertext(plaintext_len + EVP_CIPHER_block_size(cipher), '\0');
        unsigned char* ciphertext_ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&ciphertext[0]);

        EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext_ptr, &len, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>        (plaintext.c_str()), plaintext_len);
        ciphertext_len += len;

        EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext_ptr + len, &len);
        ciphertext_len += len;

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        return ciphertext.substr(0, ciphertext_len);
    }

    std::string AESEncryption::decrypt(const std::string& ciphertext, unsigned char* ivv)
    {

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
        EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, cipher, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(key.c_str()), ivv);

        int len = 0, plaintext_len = 0;
        int ciphertext_len = ciphertext.length();

        std::string plaintext(ciphertext_len, '\0');
        unsigned char* plaintext_ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&plaintext[0]);

        EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext_ptr, &len, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(ciphertext.c_str()), ciphertext_len);
        plaintext_len += len;

        EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext_ptr + len, &len);
        plaintext_len += len;

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        return plaintext.substr(0, plaintext_len);
    }
```

The encryption and decryption functions seem to be working fine. My question is whether this is too simple and how I can improve the security of the encryption. The project is intended to be part of my practical engineering thesis. I want to demonstrate the use of OpenSSL to implement a text encryption application, similar to websites where you can encrypt text using AES.

After calling the encrypt() function, the returned value is saved to a file. Here is the encrypted text "E0 C7 51 EC BA 90 AE BC C3 93 0D D9 CA FA 38 87" from the .bin file. I would like to ask for feedback on this implementation and for tips on how to improve it. I'm wondering if I should save the IV vector together with the ciphertext and then read it in the decrypt() function. And one more question, is calculating the hash function for the ciphertext using sha256 equivalent to using HMAC?"

Comment: If you want help improving working code, you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so, please delete the question here.

Comment: Also, there is [security.se] for questions about security, but I don't the rules and what questions are accepted there, you'd have to read about it before posting.

Comment: you should always use a random IV and a different IV for each message, the IV itself isn't secret so is normally just sent in plain text alongside the message